# Drive unable to be initialized in Windows 8.1 - "The device is not ready"

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, windows-8.1, sata

I've got a Western Digital WD10EZEX drive that arrived today. It is a replacement for another drive of the same make and model. I'm plugging it in to a Plugable [Hard Drive Dock](http://plugable.com/products/USB3-SATA-U3), which is connected to a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro. When I try to initialize it (both as a MBR or GPT) in Windows Disk Manager, it gives the following dialog:

[image: Error]

The drive is raw with no partitions or anything. What do I do to put a partition on this drive?

Comment: Can you format it through `Diskpart`?

Comment: Well, possibly. I'd like explicit instructions on how to do so.

Comment: Give that a go: http://www.techhack.co.uk/2011/03/31/format-a-hard-drive-with-command-prompt/

Comment: @MichaelFrank tried it, but realized that there were no volumes on the disk (no partitions = no volumes). I tried [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727978(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_CMD) but upon trying `create partition primary` on disk 1, I received `DiskPart has encountered an error: The device is not ready. See the System Event Log for more information.`

Comment: Sounds like the dock/harddrive needs to be reseated or the dock is bad.  Generally, if you're following the proper order (disk-to-dock, then dock-to-computer), it should spin up without a problem, unless the dock doesn't have the capability to read that particular drive.